# how to create empty numpy array to store different kinds of data

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to start with an empty numpy array. As the code progresses the first column should be filled with `datetime.datetime`, the second column should be filled with `str`, the third columns with `float`, and fourth column with `int`.

I tried the following:

```
A = np.empty([10, 4])
A[0][0] = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0)
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Comment: [`Structured arrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) could be one option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A structured array approach:

define a dtype according to your column specs:

```
In [460]: dt=np.dtype('O,U10,f,i')
In [461]: from datetime import datetime
```

Initalize an empty array, with 3 elements (not 3x4)

```
In [462]: A = np.empty((3,), dtype=dt)
In [463]: A
Out[463]: 
array([(None, '', 0.0, 0), (None, '', 0.0, 0), (None, '', 0.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<U10'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

fill in some values - by field name (not column number)

```
In [464]: A['f1']=['one','two','three']
In [465]: A['f0'][0]=datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0)    
In [467]: A['f2']=np.arange(3)
In [468]: A
Out[468]: 
array([(datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0), 'one', 0.0, 0),
       (None, 'two', 1.0, 0), 
       (None, 'three', 2.0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<U10'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

View on element of this array:

```
In [469]: A[0]
Out[469]: (datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0), 'one', 0.0, 0)
```

I chose to make the 1st field `object` dtype, so it can hold a `datetime` object - which isn't a number or string.

`np.datetime64` stores a date as a float, and provides a lot of functionality that `datetime` objects don't:

```
In [484]: dt1=np.dtype('datetime64[s],U10,f,i')
In [485]: A1 = np.empty((3,), dtype=dt1)
In [486]: A1['f0']=datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0)
In [487]: A1['f3']=np.arange(3)
In [488]: A1
Out[488]: 
array([(datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0), '', 0.0, 0),
       (datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0), '', 0.0, 1),
       (datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0), '', 0.0, 2)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[s]'), ('f1', '<U10'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

A third approach is to make the whole array object dtype.  That's effectively a glorified list.  Many operations resort to plain iteration, or just aren't implemented.  It's more general but you loose a lot of the power of normal numeric arrays.

Comment: This was super useful in combination with the docs:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dtype=object`.

```
A = np.empty([10, 4], dtype=object)
A[0][0] = datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 1, 0)
```

It is also possible to use structured arrays, but then you have a fixed length for string objects. If you need arbitrary big objects you have to use `dtype=object`. But this often contradicts the purpose of arrays.

Comment: What do you mean "contradicts purpose of arrays"? Does it affect performance?

Comment: Never saw this comment, sorry. Don't have any reference, so please crosscheck before relying on my answer: An array with `dtype=object` is not as efficient. The size of the objects is not known, therefore no contiguous memory can be reserved. Most likely, the array simply saves pointers to the memory location. Therefore, `dtype=object` array give you the convenience of NumPy (advanced slicing and similar things), but not all the performance benefit.